# Java, posts cript

Tags: java

I need to dynamically read the text from `.txt` file, I will find the particular text is **X** value starting position and ending position of the text. let example is, assume that following text read from `.txt` files

`Christine S. Wheatley, Vice Pres./Senior Counsel/Assistant Secretary`

and assume that **X** value starting position is 175 and ending position is 370. Here, there is one more line will start the **X** position from 350 so my text will overlapped on the line, so the text **X**'s end position within 350 suppose, the would be overlapped that, the particular text will go and start next line.

give me some help code how can I achieve that

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't I can understand what your problem is. Could you elaborate? Do you simply want to read a substring from a file with a specific start and end index?

Comment: I couldn't get your question clear, but if you are looking for position `175` to either a `linefeed` or target position(`370`), you would set the file cursor to `175` and just attempt to read (370-175) bytes. for each byte you read, check the value if it's end of line, then give up the rest read.